# How to overwrite a text file from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am aware you can append to the end of a file with batch like so...

```
echo I like turtles >> file.txt
```

but I would like to overwrite the file instead.
How could this be done?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Just answered my own question, this works:

```
echo I like turtles > file.txt

                    ^
                    |
            Just one of these
```

Comment: and worthy of an upvote therefore, although you could have written echo I like turtles > file.txt so file.txt doesn't contain quotes.

Answer (score 11):

You can use > instead of >>
: this will overwrite the file

Answer (score 5):

Use only one ">". 
Example:

`echo "I like turtles" > file.txt`

this will overwirte file.txt content.

Comment: could variable be saved similarly?


e.g:  echo %xyz% > file.txt